# Tags for visual select vs. visual mode

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a [visual-mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-mode) tag and a [visual-select](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-select) tag.

The problem is that the term "visual mode" is overloaded: there's [visual mode](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/visual.txt.html) and there's the [`:visual` command to return from Ex mode to Normal mode](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Avisual).

How shall we resolve this mess?

Comment: How often do you think the `:visual` command will be used?

Comment: And wouldn't the :visual command be [tag:visual-command] (if it needed a tag at all)?

Comment: @muru I doubt that there will be any interesting questions about the `:visual` command anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [visual-mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-mode) for consistency with [normal-mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/normal-mode), [insert-mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insert-mode), etc. It'd be weird to have one of the modes named different, and just having a command (that likely won't get questions anyway) with the same name doesn't seem like reason enough. (And, btw, there are `:normal` and `:insert` commands, too).

Retag the ones that are [visual-select](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-select). Do not use that tag (after it has no questions for a little bit, the system will delete it).

There is also a Select Mode, see vim's `:help select-mode`. That mode is different than visual mode, I suggest it be tagged [select-mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/select-mode). Again, to keep all mode tags consistent.

I think we should in general strongly favor the names used by Vim itself, and only use our own name when there is a compelling reason (e.g., confusion with other vi-like editors, technical limitations of Stack Exchange software, just plain too long, …)

Comment: How about [tag:visual-select-mode] instead?

Comment: @200_success vim clearly calls it "visual mode" (see, e.g., `:help visual-mode`). There is a `:normal` command as well—and an `:insert` command.  Not sure why `:visual` is a reason to depart from the name vim uses for this one tag.

Comment: @200_success ... actually there is a select mode as well, which is different than visual mode. So I think I'm going to change my answer.

Comment: Well reasoned. I don't disagree, but I'll explain the sequence of events that led here. [tag:visual-mode] was the original tag. Some users later introduced [tag:visual-select]. I was going to canonicalize them all to [tag:visual-mode] when I realized that the `:visual` command has a mode-switching effect that is potentially confusing, since it doesn't actually switch into visual mode. (In contrast, `:normal` does some Normal mode stuff, and `:insert` inserts text — all very logical.)

Comment: Actually, "Select mode looks like Visual mode", and you can toggle between visual mode and select mode with Ctrl-G. It's even documented in `visual.txt`. Clearly, they are closely related to each other. Perhaps they should be covered under an umbrella [tag:visual-select-mode] tag after all?

Comment: @200_success sure, they look similar, but behave differently. You can switch between them by using a mode switching command (C-G), but you can switch from normal or insert to select as well. Or from select to insert or normal. Select mode is probably closer to insert mode, actually. At least in terms of the behavior of most keystrokes.

Comment: How would you tag [this question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/769/24) — [tag:visual-mode], [tag:select-mode], or both?

Comment: @200_success that's [tag:visual-mode]. And of course [tag:unix] or better would be [tag:x11]. [tag:select-mode] is different; the key thing about select mode is that when you type, the selection is *replaced* with whatever you type. Sort of like how a selection works everywhere except vim.

Comment: `visual-select` should be a tag synonym for `visual-mode`, so that people who try `select` as a tag for their question will get `visual-mode` suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The current four questions tagged [visual-mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-mode) and three questions tagged [visual-select](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-select) are actually all on the same topic.  Therefore, we should combine them into one tag.  Since "visual mode" has a slight possibility of misinterpretation, let's go with [visual-select](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-select) and abolish the [visual-mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-mode) tag.

Comment: If someone would ask me "Hey, I try to do foo in Vim's visual select and it doesn't work", then my first reply would be a slightly confused look, and the question "you mean visual mode?" ... So in other words, I don't think that "visual-select" is very obvious ...